# why does my cloth simulations "bounces" when previewing?

Tags: rendering, cloth-simulation, cache

I'm playing with cloth simulation, and I got some weird shit.

It's like the simulation wasn't linear; but was calculating a frame every ~10 frames; then interpolating between for the preview.  Is this possible ?

When I keep it playing, it seems that the cache continues to fill, but at the end of my animation - here near frame ~75.
Why isn't this linear / How can I make it simulate in a linear way ?

Thanks!

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: can this be related to my "sync" parameter being actually on "AV Sync" ?

Comment: Is your frame step set to 1?

Comment: Yes of course :)